# Share websocket data with multiple components in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, components

I have 1 main component. Inside of this component i use WebSockets to receive data from the server. I receive an object with a range of fields inside it. The number of fileds can be from 0 till 10, for example. Each time i receive an object i use `forEach()` to take all fields. For each field i need to init a component, like this:

```js
self.dcl.loadIntoLocation(StreamComponent, self.elementRef, 'stream');
```

If a copy of a component for current field of an object already exists, i need to update it with new received data within the view. The main my problem is i don't know how to pass the data from WebSockets to created component. I can create and init it, but i never mind how to pass data to it. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to leverage the promise returned by the method:

```
self.dcl.loadIntoLocation(
  StreamComponent, self.elementRef, 'stream').then((compRef:ComponentRef) => {
    compRef.instance.someAttr = something;
});
```

This promise allows you to get the instance of the newly created component and set data in its properties (for example, the web socket).

Comment: I test this code.

`self.dcl.loadIntoLocation(StreamComponent, self.elementRef, 'stream').then((compRef: ComponentRef) => {
                compRef.instance = {name: 'name'};
                console.log(compRef);
            });`

I hardcode variable `name` to test it.

Comment: No in fact, you should use this: `self.dcl.loadIntoLocation(StreamComponent, self.elementRef, 'stream').then((compRef: ComponentRef) => { compRef.instance.name =  'name'}; console.log(compRef); });`. Otherwise you override the component instance itself...